# Remove blank lines from command output stored in a variable

Tags: powershell

My variable output may have 100 lines. This is how it appears:

```
VOLUME #28
 drive letter        = I:
 dev_name            = \Device\HarddiskVolume8
 guid_name           = \\?\Volume{35596739-d159-11e4-80c1-0050569cf1fd}
 size                = 5117 MB.
 disk tag            = 0x000000304f65e304.
 descriptor          = \\.\Volume{35596739-d159-11e4-80c1-0050569cf1fd}

 **** ERROR: DATA NOT AVAILABLE [0x00000100] ****

VOLUME #28
 drive letter        = B:
 dev_name            = \Device\HarddiskVolume63
 guid_name           = \\?\Volume{3bf4ee0a-d050-11e4-80be-0050569cf1fd}
 size                = 81917 MB.
 disk tag            = 0x000000304f65e304.
 descriptor          = \\.\Volume{3bf4ee0a-d050-11e4-80be-0050569cf1fd}

 **** ERROR: DATA NOT AVAILABLE [0x00000100] ****
```

**This is how I want it to look like:**

```
VOLUME #29
 drive letter        = I:
 dev_name            = \Device\HarddiskVolume8
 guid_name           = \\?\Volume{35596739-d159-11e4-80c1-0050569cf1fd}
 size                = 5117 MB.
 disk tag            = 0x000000304f65e304.
 descriptor          = \\.\Volume{35596739-d159-11e4-80c1-0050569cf1fd}
 **** ERROR: DATA NOT AVAILABLE [0x00000100] ****
VOLUME #28
 drive letter        = B:
 dev_name            = \Device\HarddiskVolume63
 guid_name           = \\?\Volume{3bf4ee0a-d050-11e4-80be-0050569cf1fd}
 size                = 81917 MB.
 disk tag            = 0x000000304f65e304.
 descriptor          = \\.\Volume{3bf4ee0a-d050-11e4-80be-0050569cf1fd}
 **** ERROR: DATA NOT AVAILABLE [0x00000100] ****
```

I'm checking to see if there is a way to remove the blank lines in the  variable. Thank you!

Comment: It is not an array. I pushed the command output into a variable and the output appears as above.

Comment: Check it: `$yourvariable.GetType()`. External command output is usually an array.

Comment: I agree. we can make it an array too. $c=(command)

Comment: BaseType is System.Array

Comment: Parentheses don't make it an array. PowerShell stores external commands output in an array when it has multiple lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that with a regex:

```
(?m)^\s*?\n
```

Where `(?m)` sets the multi line flag, `^` asserts position at start of a line, `\s*?` matches any whitespace character between zero and unlimited times (non greedy) and `\n` matches a linefeed.

---

**Example:**

```
$myVar = 
@'
VOLUME #28
 drive letter        = I:
 dev_name            = \Device\HarddiskVolume8
 guid_name           = \\?\Volume{35596739-d159-11e4-80c1-0050569cf1fd}
 size                = 5117 MB.
 disk tag            = 0x000000304f65e304.
 descriptor          = \\.\Volume{35596739-d159-11e4-80c1-0050569cf1fd}

 **** ERROR: DATA NOT AVAILABLE [0x00000100] ****

VOLUME #28
 drive letter        = B:
 dev_name            = \Device\HarddiskVolume63
 guid_name           = \\?\Volume{3bf4ee0a-d050-11e4-80be-0050569cf1fd}
 size                = 81917 MB.
 disk tag            = 0x000000304f65e304.
 descriptor          = \\.\Volume{3bf4ee0a-d050-11e4-80be-0050569cf1fd}

 **** ERROR: DATA NOT AVAILABLE [0x00000100] ****
'@

$myVar -replace '(?m)^\s*?\n'
```

**Output:**

```
VOLUME #28
 drive letter        = I:
 dev_name            = \Device\HarddiskVolume8
 guid_name           = \\?\Volume{35596739-d159-11e4-80c1-0050569cf1fd}
 size                = 5117 MB.
 disk tag            = 0x000000304f65e304.
 descriptor          = \\.\Volume{35596739-d159-11e4-80c1-0050569cf1fd}
 **** ERROR: DATA NOT AVAILABLE [0x00000100] ****
VOLUME #28
 drive letter        = B:
 dev_name            = \Device\HarddiskVolume63
 guid_name           = \\?\Volume{3bf4ee0a-d050-11e4-80be-0050569cf1fd}
 size                = 81917 MB.
 disk tag            = 0x000000304f65e304.
 descriptor          = \\.\Volume{3bf4ee0a-d050-11e4-80be-0050569cf1fd}
 **** ERROR: DATA NOT AVAILABLE [0x00000100] ****
```

Comment: Since this answer won't work on the OP's data specifically but could be useful in other cases, you may want to add a clarification: `In case your variable is a single multi-line string confirmed by $myVar.GetType() showing Name = String`

Answer (score 0):

Your variable is an output from external utility, so **it's an array** as you can see by checking its type: `$output.GetType()` will show `System.Object[]` which means an array.

Simply use an array comparison operator:

```
$noBlanks = $output -ne ''
```

Or regex that also filters out lines with just spaces and tabs:

```
$noBlanks = $output -notmatch '^\s*$'
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, here is the variable definition -
`$volCkeck=& "C:\Script\command.exe" v`
This variable will have the output pasted in the question. Tried the recommendations. but doesn't remove the blank lines. :|

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem: `'list disk'|out-file ($env:TEMP+'\1.txt') -encoding ASCII; $output = & "diskpart" /s ($env:TEMP+'\1.txt'); $output -ne ''` Anyway, the answer is correct so the problem is something else.

Comment: Thank you! Can we do `$list = Get-Disk`? this will have blank spaces in the variable output. And if I do, `$listdisk= $list -ne ''` or `$listdisk= $list -nomatch '^\s*$'`, doesn't remove blank lines..

Comment: It's an entirely different situation. The **internal** `Get-Disk` cmdlet gets one or more Disk **objects**. What you see on screen is a text representation, but inside those are objects and of course they can't be filtered with plain string matching. You may convert the output to a multi-line string and use Martin Brandl's answer.